# Python ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence when deploying to heroku

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm using the following code to find the newest file in the list:

```
db_file_list = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\atammaro\\Desktop\\Stefanini\\*.db')
latest_db = max(db_file_list, key=os.path.getctime)
```

Im getting the following error:  ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such directory in Heroku container, so your `glob.glob(...)` returns `[]`, then you pass it to `max(...)`, which can't pick maximum value from an empty list, so it raises `ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

As the path `'C:\\Users\\atammaro\\Desktop\\Stefanini\\*.db'` doesn't exist in the Heroku environment - the `glob.glob` function returns an empty list. You pass that empty list to the `max` function which cannot pick a maximum value from an empty list and therefore raises a `ValueError`.

SQLite3 is a great DB for development, however Heroku's dynos don't have a filesystem that persists across deploys, and therefore a file-based database like SQLite3 isn't going work here.

Heroku has a Postgres offering that will suit - with a free tier and a basic tier that are good for small projects. The biggest benefit over SQLite is that you get backups that you wouldn't get otherwise (plus all the other Postgres features).

There's a guide to updating your settings.py to use Postgres [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings).